# SelectList without using hardcode names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

Is there a *quick* way that create a SelectList without using hardcode names:

```
myViewModelVM.Companies = new SelectList(companies , "Id", "CompanyName");
```

rest of code:

```
public class MyViewModelVM
{
    public SelectList Companies { get; set; }
}

MyEntities myEntities = new MyEntities();
List<Company> companies = myEntities.Companies.ToList();
```

**EDIT**

So far I got this:

```
myViewModelVM.Companies  = new SelectList(
                              companies.Select(n => new SelectListItem() 
                                 { Text = n.Id.ToString(), Value = n.CompanyName }), 
                                 "Text", "Value"
                           );
```

Although this is still harcode, `Text` and `Value` are standart values

Comment: `quick way` means in one line

Comment: You'll still need to define somewhere what the value and text field is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some sort of convention to map Id and CompanyName to Value and Text, unless you want to decorate your model classes with customattributes.

This use less hardwiring and gives you an option to extend the mapping. I subclassed `SelectList` and you can add anytype to it. It maps a property that is name id to Value and a property that has `Name` in it to `Text`.

```
public class SelectListAuto<T>: SelectList
{
    public SelectListAuto(IEnumerable list):base(list, GetId(typeof(T)), GetName(typeof(T)))
    {
    }

    static string GetId(Type t) {
       // you can have all kind logic to autowire up, ie use some convention
       return t.GetProperties()
              .Where(p => p.Name.Equals("Id",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
              .Select(p=>p.Name).First();
    }

    static string GetName(Type t) {
       // you can have all kind logic to autowire up, ie use some convention
       return t.GetProperties()
              .Where(p => p.Name.IndexOf("Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 )
              .Select(p=>p.Name).First();
    }
}
```

Typical usage will look like this:

```
var l = new List<Company> { 
   new Company {Id =1, CompanyName="test"},
   new Company {Id =2, CompanyName="foo"},
   new Company {Id =1, CompanyName="bar"}
};

var sl = new SelectListAuto<Company>(l);
```

One other option would be to decorate your model classes with an attribute:

```
public class Company
{
  [Value]
  public int Id { get;set;}
  [Text]
  public string CompanyName {get;set;}
}

// CustomAttribute
public class Value:Attribute {}
```

In the `SelectListAuto` we would select the property with the Customattribute instead, like so:

```
static string GetId(Type t) {
   // you can have all kind logic to autowire up, ie use some convention
   t.GetProperties().Select(p => p.CustomAttributes).Dump();
   return t.GetProperties()
          .Where(p => p.Name
                      .Equals("Id",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                      p.CustomAttributes.Any(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(Value)) 
   ).Select(p=>p.Name).First();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyViewModelVM.Companies = new SelectList(companies , "Id", "CompanyName");
```

rest of code:

```
public class MyViewModelVM
{
    public SelectList Companies { get; set; }
}

MyEntities myEntities = new MyEntities();
List<Company> companies = myEntities.Companies.ToList();

SelectList compList = new SelectList()
foreach(var item in companies)
{
   complist.Add(item[0], item[1]); //please take care of the proper syntax here.
  //or
   complist.Add(item.items[0], item.items[1].toString());

  //but this way you can add without hardcoding field names
}
```